# About cufft R2C and C2R

Tags: c++, cuda, cufft

I have used the cufft to do my research, but there some problem about to use it. The steps of mine is under below:

1. do forward FFT on the image by using R2C
2. multiply the kernel coefficients with the complex results
3. do the inverse FFT on the multiplying results by using C2R

But, when I used the complex results to multiply the kernel, a serious problem happened, the cufft complex results is not equal to the results of fftw and there are lots of zero in the result. I know the size of result of R2C is N1(N2/2+1), but I want to got the complete complex results. How to solve this problem? i.e. How to restore the R2C results? And how to put the multiplying results into C2R and get the right answer?

My implement program code is under below:

```
__global__ void MultiplyKernel(cufftComplex *data, float *data1,cufftComplex *data2, unsigned vectorSize) {
    unsigned idx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
    if (idx < vectorSize){
        data[idx].x = data2[idx].x*data1[idx];
        data[idx].y = data2[idx].y*data1[idx];
    }
}

__global__ void Scale(cufftReal *data, unsigned vectorSize) {
    unsigned idx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
    if (idx < vectorSize){
        data[idx] = data[idx]/vectorSize;
    }
}

void ApplyKernel1(cufftReal *data2, float *ImageBuffer, float *KernelBuffer, unsigned int NX, unsigned int NY,unsigned int NZ)
{
      float *Akernel;
      cufftComplex *data_dev1, *data_dev2;
      cufftReal *data_dev3, *data_dev;
      cudaMalloc((void **)&Akernel, NX * NY * NZ * sizeof(float));
      cudaMalloc((void **)&data_dev3, NX * NY * NZ * sizeof(cufftReal));
      cudaMalloc((void **)&data_dev, NX * NY * NZ * sizeof(cufftComplex));
      cudaMalloc((void **)&data_dev1, NX * NY * NZ * sizeof(cufftComplex));
      cudaMalloc((void **)&data_dev2, NX * NY * NZ * sizeof(cufftComplex));
      cudaMemset(data_dev, 0, NX * NY * NZ * sizeof(cufftReal));
      cudaMemset(data_dev1, 0, NX * NY * NZ * sizeof(cufftComplex));
      cudaMemset(data_dev2, 0, NX * NY * NZ * sizeof(cufftComplex));
      //cufftComplex *resultFFT = (cufftComplex*)malloc(NX * NY * NZ * sizeof(cufftComplex));
      //cufftReal *resultIFFT = (cufftReal*)malloc(NX * NY * NZ * sizeof(cufftReal));

      cudaMemcpy(data_dev, ImageBuffer, NX * NY * NZ * sizeof(cufftReal), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

      cufftHandle plan;
      cufftPlan3d(&plan, NZ, NY, NX, CUFFT_R2C);
      cufftExecR2C(plan, data_dev, data_dev1);

      //Multiply kernel
      cudaMemcpy(Akernel, KernelBuffer, NX * NY * NZ * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
      static const int BLOCK_SIZE = 1000;
      const int blockCount = (NX*NY*NZ+BLOCK_SIZE-1)/BLOCK_SIZE;
      MultiplyKernel <<<blockCount, BLOCK_SIZE>>> (data_dev2, Akernel, data_dev1, NX*NY*NZ);


      cufftDestroy(plan);
      //cufftPlan3d(&plan, NZ, NY, NX, CUFFT_C2R);
      cufftPlan3d(&plan, NZ,NY,NX, CUFFT_C2R);
      cufftExecC2R(plan, data_dev2, data_dev3 );
      Scale <<<blockCount, BLOCK_SIZE>>> (data_dev3, NX*NY*NZ);
      cudaMemcpy(data2, data_dev3, NZ * NY * NX * sizeof(cufftReal), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

      cufftDestroy(plan);
      cudaFree(data_dev);
      cudaFree(data_dev1);
      cudaFree(data_dev2);
      cudaFree(data_dev3);
      cudaFree(Akernel);


}
```

Comment: you do unserstand that the R2C and C2R transforms are symmetrical, and that CUFFT only computes one half of the solution because of this?

Comment: why not just do everything with C2C operations?

Comment: Yes, I have used C2C to do forward transform by set the data.y to 0, and got the right results. But, finally after multiplying the coefficients, I want to do backward  transform to get the real results, i.e. C2R(backward), how do I get the right answer by using the cufft library? (note： I have multiplied some coefficients to the C2C results.)

Answer (score 1):

When you multiply the results of the R2C fft by a complex number, the results no longer correspond to a symmetric array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I asked that how to get the complete result from the R2C results which is equal to the C2C results. I want the whole results because I want to multiply it by some coefficients, can you help me?

Comment: @KwuJohn The number of complex number is half the number of real because the response of the frequency n-k is the complex conjugate of response of the frequency k if the input array is real. If your filter does not preserve this property, the filtered signal will not be purely real and using C2R to get back to the real world seems flawed!